# Address Bar on PWA WebApp (Android) does not go away on adding assetslink.json

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA WebApp from my existing website. On Installing the apk on Android device, the address bar shows on top. I tried uploading the assetslink.json file on the server but still same issue.

When trying to access the assetslink file on browser i get the issue "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')"

Please help.

[image: manifest.json]

Answer (score 0):

Add homepage to your package.json like below

```
"homepage": "./"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Firefox for Android not supporting TWAs, my solution was to make Chrome the default browser for my Android device.